# getting UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment in python

Tags: python

```
def delta_next_car_1(pos_next,lane):
   i=pos_next
   if i+lane[i]>=L:
      for x in range(i+1,i+lane[i]+1):
          if x < L:
             if lane[x]!=-1:
                d_n= x-i-1
                break
          else :
             if lane[x%L]!=-1:
                d_n= L+((x%L)-i-1)
                break
   else:            
      for x in range(i+1,i+lane[i]+1):
          if lane[x]!=-1:
              d_n=x-i-1
              break
return d_n

L=15
lane=[-1,3,-1,-1,-1,-2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,4,-1,-1,-1]
pn=11
d_nxt=delta_next_car_1(pn,lane)
print(d_nxt)
```

for the above code, I am getting the below error while calling delta_next_car_1() function.
Error message:

```
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12684/3388299041.py in 
 delta_next_car_1(pos_next, lane)
     20                 d_n=x-i-1
     21                 break
---> 22     return d_n

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'd_n' referenced before assignment
```

I am not able to understand where I went wrong. Could someone please help me

Comment: If you copy your code correctly, you forgot to indent this return statement

Comment: You try to return `d_n`, but there are several cases where you don't assign a value to it before. Example: if `range(i+1,i+lane[i]+1)` is empty you never enter one of the loops.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you either need to assign a value for the variable to your if/else statement.

```
for x in range(i+1,i+lane[i]+1):
    if x < L:
        if lane[x]!=-1:
            d_n= x-i-1
            break
        d_n = XXXXXXXXXX
    else :
        if lane[x%L]!=-1:
            d_n= L+((x%L)-i-1)
            break
        d_n = XXXXXXXXXX
```

Or, assign d_n before your checks:

```
def delta_next_car_1(pos_next,lane):
    d_n = xxxxxxxxx
    i=pos_next
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because "The error occurred because the program referenced the local variable before it was declared inside the function ." source [tutorial](https://office54.net/python/error/unbound-local-error)

So it is needed to initialize(declared) the variable `d_n` before referring to it. In the example solution, it is initialized by `0` but can be declared by any value required.

```
def delta_next_car_1(pos_next, lane):
    d_n = 0 #initialized by a default value
    i = pos_next
    if i + lane[i] >= L:
        for x in range(i + 1, i + lane[i] + 1):
            if x < L:
                if lane[x] != -1:
                    d_n = x - i - 1
                break
            else:
                if lane[x % L] != -1:
                    d_n = L + ((x % L) - i - 1)
                break
    else:
        for x in range(i + 1, i + lane[i] + 1):
            if lane[x] != -1:
                d_n = x - i - 1
                break
    return d_n


L = 15
lane = [-1, 3, -1, -1, -1, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1, -1]
pn = 11
d_nxt = delta_next_car_1(pn, lane)
print(d_nxt)
```